# ASP.NET MVC 3 RAZOR : How to use POST, it gives error "Resource can not found"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, get, http-post

Following are controller and view. When [submit] button is being click application raises a error "resource can not found". I know using Get and Post is very basic concept of MVC. Would any make me the concept clear with some practical scenario when to use Get and Post and WHAT IS WRONG WITH FOLLOWING CODES.

## Controller:

```
namespace MVCModelBinding.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")] 
        public ActionResult IndexPost()
        {
            if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
            {

                string id = Request.Form["ID"];

                string fname = Request.Form["FirstName"];

                string lname = Request.Form["LastName"];

                ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Employee data received successfully for ID " + id + "!";

            }

            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

## view (index.chtml)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexPost", "HomeController",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Employee ID
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("ID")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First name
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("FirstName")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("LastName")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The action name and controller name used for the form are wrong. It should be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

The action name is just `"Index"` because that's what you specified with `ActionNameAttribute`. The controller name should not include the "Controller" suffix.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Can actionlink like @Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index"); be used to post a form instead of <input type="submit" value="Submit" />.? OR actionlink always look for GET method??

Comment: @Paul: A link by itself will not submit a form, that's standard browser behavior mandated by HTML and has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. You can make it submit a form (and choose that the submit be done by `POST`) using Javascript, but you will need to code the "on click serialize the form and make an AJAX request" behavior manually.